# REGEX to match multi lines

Tags: python, regex

Having trouble matching a regex for multiple lines.
I've tried a few but with no luck.

**First Try:**
((?:\b# show)(?:.*\n?){6})

**Result:** Failed. Found out that the lines can be anywhere between 5-8 sometimes less or more. So matching 6 times won't work.

**Second Try:**
(?<=#\n)(show.*?version)

**Result:** Failed: Does not match on anything although I've used similar regex with success on other matches.

**String I'm trying to match.**

```
wgb-car1# show startup-config
Using 6149 out of 32768 bytes
!
! NVRAM config last updated at 15:50:05 UTC Wed Oct 1 2014 by user
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
```

**I'm trying to match everything from show to the version number.**

This regex works **(?s)# show(.*)version** but I don't know how to get the numbers as they can be any combination of decimals, but always numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following *regex* :

```
(?s)#\sshow\s*(.*?)version\s*([\d.]+)
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/MKXWqq/2)**

**python** ([demo](https://ideone.com/h8VcaG))

```
import re

s = """wgb-car1# show startup-config
Using 6149 out of 32768 bytes
!
! NVRAM config last updated at 15:50:05 UTC Wed Oct 1 2014 by user
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!"""
r = r"(?s)#\sshow\s*(.*?)version\s*([\d.]+)"
o = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r, s)]
print o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try matching newlines up to the version number, and then not matching newlines afterwards. You can use `(?sm:show.*\nversion)` to get the multi-line behavior (with the `(?sm:...)` settings) and then just something like `.*$` afterwards, non-multiline.

Answer (score 0):

One answer (among others) uses a pos. lookahead:

```
\#\ show
([\s\S]+?)
(?=version)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/RUTt7y/1).

---

As full `Python` example:

```
import re

string = """
wgb-car1# show startup-config
Using 6149 out of 32768 bytes
!
! NVRAM config last updated at 15:50:05 UTC Wed Oct 1 2014 by user
!
version 12.4
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    \#\ show
    ([\s\S]+?)
    (?=version)
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

matches = [match.group(0) for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(matches)
# ['# show startup-config\nUsing 6149 out of 32768 bytes\n!\n! NVRAM config last updated at 15:50:05 UTC Wed Oct 1 2014 by user\n!\n']
```